# Pass list of objects from aspx.cs file to aspx file

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, webforms

I'm struggling with some issue. I have an object with three string properties

```
public Class SuperObject {
public string Name { get; set; }
public string Destintation { get; set; }
public string ActionName { get; set; }
}
```

I want to pass a list of this object instances'.

Code example:

```
public partial class PrintTasks: System.Web.UI.Page
{
public BindingList<SuperObject> mySuperObjectList = new BindingList<SuperObject>();
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
  var myObject = new SuperObject();
  myObject.Name = "I";
  myObject.Destination = "Love";
  myObject.ActionName = "StackOverFlow";
  mySuperObjectList.Add(myObject);
  //What next?
 }
}
```

Assuming this code compiles and no warnings appear ...

I have no idea how to pass this list from aspx.cs file to aspx file and then print it on the webside. I assume, I have to do something with JSON and JavaScript.

Comment: Have a look at data binding, e.g: http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-aspnet-45-web-forms/display_data_items_and_details

Comment: What control are you using to render it? Have you tried reading e.g. http://weblogs.asp.net/gurusarkar/binding-list-of-custom-class-to-gridview-or-listview-control?

Comment: Thank you for a quick answer! I will try what you sent me. Do you know any possibility to pass c# object to javaScript?

Comment: no idea how to use it :,

Comment: According to your code it seems that you want to pass from page to ascx.

Comment: Am I? I actually wanted to pass from aspx.cs to aspx. I read about a binding, but is there any possibility to pass arguments via JavaScript?

Comment: I thought that if I constructed some code in Page_Load method I would receive the objects while the page was being loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out.

I serialized the list of objects in aspx.cs file and then parsed it in aspx. Anyway, thanks!

Comment: Great Matt! We are happy for you. Maybe you should put here some code examples.. why or how..